# Using mutate, if_else and replace I get In x[list] <- values : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, replace, dplyr, conditional-statements

I know this subject has been covered several times in SO but I could not find an answer to my problem.

I have the following data (edited, added the full real data):

```
structure(list(Expo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("DC", "DI"), class = "factor"), 
    day = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), SYN = c("S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", "S", "U", "N", 
    "S", "U", "N", "S", "U"), freq.n = c(19L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 12L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 24L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 8L, 49L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 12L, 7L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 38L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 105L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 11L, 21L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 67L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 
    4L, 97L, 19L, 10L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 95L, 14L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 153L, 
    56L, 13L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 82L, 33L, 10L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 82L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 20L, 5L, 3L, 30L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 66L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 23L, 1L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 53L, 11L, 3L, 1L, 108L, 18L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 101L, 14L, 4L, 1L, 122L, 
    33L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 65L, 20L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 11L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -224L))
```

I ran the following code:

```
library(dplyr)

q = c("3" = "1",
      "5" = "3",
      "7" = "5",
      "9" = "7",
      "10" = "8")

Pi %>% 
mutate(day = if_else(Expo == "DC", 
                     replace(day, day == day, q), as.character(day)))
```

I get this warning **In x[list] <- values :   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length** with the following result.

After edition of the question: A subsetted example of what I get.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Expo  day   SYN   freq.n
  <fct> <chr> <chr>  <int>
1 DC    1     S         19
2 DC    3     U          6
3 DC    5     N          1
4 DC    7     S          4
5 DC    8     U          2
6 DC    1     N          3
```

It is clearly assigning incorrect values in "day".

The expected output should be:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Expo  day   SYN   freq.n 
  <fct> <chr> <chr>  <int>
1 DC    1     S         19
2 DC    1     U          6 
3 DC    1     N          1 
4 DC    1     S          4 
5 DC    1     U          2 
6 DC    1     N          3
```

The thing is that the very same line of code runs perfectly with a similar tbl.

I would appreciate some comment that can point me in the right direction.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `day == day` returns always `TRUE`, six times. But the length of `q` is 5. Can you show the expected output? Also, for your example `Expo == "DC"` is true for all rows. Maybe make the data more 'realistic'?!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I added the data as the columns that I am more interested in.

Comment: Also added expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dplyr::case_when`... does this do what you want?

case_when allows for multiple conditions to be applied to a vector, in this case there on only one condition so case_when works as an if else condition:

The condition is defined by `Expo == "DC"` when it is TRUE the formula tilde "~" instigates what to do, which is to replace the value for `day` from a named vector. The second part of case_when i.e. the `TRUE ~ as.character(day)` mops up the unresolved elements of the vector, it can be treated as the "else" part of and if else conditional i.e. it deals with all the cases where (counter intuitively) the result of the condition is FALSE. Another way of looking at it is to say all the elements not affected by the previous case_when are TRUE and the ~ lets R know what to do with them.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(day = case_when(Expo == "DC" ~ str_replace_all(day, q),
                         TRUE ~ as.character(day))) %>% 
  head(20)
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#>    Expo  day   SYN   freq.n
#>    <fct> <chr> <chr>  <int>
#>  1 DC    1     S         19
#>  2 DC    1     U          6
#>  3 DC    1     N          1
#>  4 DC    1     S          4
#>  5 DC    1     U          2
#>  6 DC    1     N          3
#>  7 DC    1     S          2
#>  8 DC    1     U          1
#>  9 DC    1     N         12
#> 10 DC    1     S         10
#> 11 DC    1     U          1
#> 12 DC    1     N          1
#> 13 DC    1     S          1
#> 14 DC    1     U          1
#> 15 DC    1     N         24
#> 16 DC    1     S          4
#> 17 DC    1     U          1
#> 18 DC    1     N          1
#> 19 DC    1     S          3
#> 20 DC    1     U          1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It does! Greatly appreciated! Can you please explained why the case_when, the "~", and the TRUE? Thanks again, you saved me some ibuprofens.

Comment: I'm not sure I've explained this particularly well in the question, but I've had a go. You could do a lot worse than read the help pages from the function documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is clear now. I am not a computer guy so these  explanations add a lot of value.